# useEffect and API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to make a dictionary using React. First of all, i have

```
const [word, setWord] = useState();
```

Then, i have the API

```
const dictionaryApi = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(
        `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${input}`
      );

      setWord(data.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

So i the word now received the data.data from the API. I saw that apparently i have to use useEffect, though i don't know why. If the useEffect's second parameter is an empty array, it will run just 1 time right? I have a button with an input, and what i wanna do is store that data from the API in an empty array. So first of all i created a array

```
const [change, setChange] = useState([]);
```

And in the click function, i wrote

```
setChange([...change, "a"]);
```

So every time i click it, it will ad an 'a'. And i passed it as the useEffect's second parameter, so when i click, the array will change, with that change useEffect will be executed.

Finally, i have another empty array that will receive `word`

```
const [resultlist, setResultlist] = useState([]);
setResultlist([...resultlist, word]);
```

But the first time i click the button, the `change` array doesn't change, only the second time i click it changes. I feel like i'm making it overcomplicated. How should i do that?

Comment: it is a bit unclear what your situation is, I advise you to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(myFunction, [data])
```

In this example myFunction will be executed each time my variable data is modified, if you provide an empty array, it will only be executed once.
If you to call your function when you click on a button you just have to pass the function to the onClick props of your button

```js
<button onClick={myFunction}>Button</button>
```

I didn't understand clearly what you want to do but if you want to add your input value to the array you received by your api, you can add it like this in the button function

```js
setWord([...word, inputValue])
```

Comment: There's something i don't get it. My const data is what i get from the API. And it's an array with a property data. So my data.data would be that returned property right? So i said that setWord(data.data). My word const received the data from the API. But why when the page load my word is an empty array? Shouldn't already be with the data.data?

Comment: the call to the API is async, so useEffect won't have anything until the promise is executed and successful. If you put data (or wherever you want to store it) in the useEffect dependency array, then the page/component will render empty and once data is filled, it'll re-render with the data